# Generating stack trace for python frontend - CPP backend

Tags: performance, operating-system, stack

I'm trying to generate a stack trace for a python program that uses pytorch. All the profilers for python out there only display all the python front end functions in the stack trace and not the CPP functions that get called behind the hood. How do I get the CPP stack trace?